# (70007)The timeout specified has expired:

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2, owncloud, nextcloud

a friend from  me has the Problem that his Nextcloud/owncloud installation don´t work correct. When he would upload some files it is really slow and stops for few seconds.

i have read that the proxytimeout is to low. At the apache2.conf it was set to 300. I changed this to 600 and add *ProxyTimeout 600*. Also i edit the vhost file and changed the  to 
but no changes.

Can anyone help?

best regards Lars

i look at his Server-Log and this is the output:

```
Thu May 25 07:39:01.000632 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24303] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:26211] AH01964: Connection to child 2 established (server cloud.domain.tld:443)
[Thu May 25 07:39:01.930903 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24302] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:58764] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server cloud.domain.tld:443)
[Thu May 25 07:39:02.348832 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24301] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:50220] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server cloud.domain.tld:443)
[Thu May 25 07:39:06.228009 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24303] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:26211] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu May 25 07:39:07.097140 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24302] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:58764] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu May 25 07:39:07.520635 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24301] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:50220] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu May 25 07:39:15.433248 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24314] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:58834] AH01964: Connection to child 8 established (server cloud.domain.tld:443)
[Thu May 25 07:39:25.314596 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 24314] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:58834] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

the sites-enabled/domain.http.conf

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80>

### YOUR SERVER ADDRESS ###
#    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
#    ServerName example.com
#    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com

### SETTINGS ###
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud

    <Directory /var/www/nextcloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
    </Directory>

    Alias /owncloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
    Dav off
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/var/ocdata">
    # just in case if .htaccess gets disabled
    Require all denied
    </Directory>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud

# Spreed WebRTC config (must be in same vhost)
#<Location /webrtc>
#ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/webrtc
#ProxyPassReverse /webrtc
#</Location>
#<Location /webrtc/ws>
#ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8080/webrtc/ws
#</Location>
#ProxyVia On
#ProxyPreserveHost On
#RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS



</VirtualHost>
```

die domain.ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443>

    Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"
    SSLEngine on

### YOUR SERVER ADDRESS ###

    ServerAdmin admin@domain.tld
    ServerName domain.tld

### SETTINGS ###

    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud

    <Directory /var/www/nextcloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
    </Directory>

    Alias /owncloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
    Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud


### LOCATION OF CERT FILES ###

#    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.tld.ca-bundle
#    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.tld.crt
#    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/SSL-Cert_domain.tld_private_Key


# Spreed WebRTC config (must be in same vhost)
<Location /webrtc>
ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/webrtc
ProxyPassReverse /webrtc
</Location>
<Location /webrtc/ws>
ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8080/webrtc/ws
</Location>
ProxyVia On
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS

## Hinzugefuegt wegen Errors und super lahm:
## Wieder rueckgaengig gemacht
#SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

and the apache2.conf

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel info

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
ServerName domain.tld
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Timeout variable value only in apache2.conf file worked for me. Dont forget to restart apache2.